# Get values from one column in two columns

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

**tArtikelAttribut**:

```
kArtikelAttribut | kArtikel | kAttribut
---------------------------------------
     97974       |     33   |    117
     97975       |     33   |    122
```

**tArtikelAttributSprache**

```
kArtikelAttribut | cWertVarchar
-------------------------------
     97974       | black
     97975       | bla
```

**tAttributSprache**

```
kAttribut | cName
------------------    
   117    | Farbe
   122    | Saison
```

My SQL:

```
SELECT 
    tArtikelAttribut.kArtikel, 
    tArtikelAttributSprache.cWertVarchar AS Farbe, 
    tArtikelAttributSprache.cWertVarchar AS Saison
FROM 
    (tArtikelAttributSprache 
INNER JOIN 
    tArtikelAttribut ON tArtikelAttributSprache.kArtikelAttribut = tArtikelAttribut.kArtikelAttribut) 
INNER JOIN 
    tAttributSprache ON tArtikelAttribut.kAttribut = tAttributSprache.kAttribut
GROUP BY 
    tArtikelAttribut.kArtikel, tArtikelAttributSprache.cWertVarchar, 
    tArtikelAttributSprache.cWertVarchar, tAttributSprache.cName
HAVING 
    (((tAttributSprache.cName) = "Farbe" OR 
      (tAttributSprache.cName) = "Saison"));
```

Output

```
kArtikel | Farbe | Saison
-------------------------
   33    | black | black
   33    | bla   | bla
```

I need this

```
kArtikel | Farbe | Saison
-------------------------
   33    | black | bla
```

I have unfortunately no solution approach

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Your example is invalid (standard) SQL so it's important that you tell us which DBMS you are using.

Comment: Also you should try using English names for your tables and columns, even though you are free to use your locale names but in the long run and code and DBMS maintenance it works better in English. Besides you will have smaller column names then

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code like:

```
SELECT 
    a.kArtikel, 
    aas.cWertVarchar, 
    cName
FROM 
    tArtikelAttribut a  INNER JOIN 
    tArtikelAttributSprache aas    ON 
    aa.kArtikelAttribut = aas.kArtikelAttribut INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
        kAttribut,
        cName
    FROM
        tAttributSprache 
    WHERE
         s.cName IN( "Farbe" ,"Saison") ) s ON 
    a.kAttribut = s.kAttribut
```

your results would be:

```
    kArtikelAttribut | kArtikel | kAttribut  | cWertVarchar | cName
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
     97974       |     33   |    117             | black   |  Farbe
     97975       |     33   |    122             | bla     |  Saison
```

so if you wanted the results you posted, you'd have to pivot over cName and select the max(cWertVarchar)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 
    a.kArtikel AS Identnummer, 
    aas.cWertVarchar, 
    cName
FROM
    tArtikelAttribut a  INNER JOIN 
    tArtikelAttributSprache aas ON 
    a.kArtikelAttribut = aas.kArtikelAttribut INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
        kAttribut,
        cName
    FROM
        tAttributSprache 
    WHERE
         cName IN ('Farbe' ,'Saison')) s ON 
    a.kAttribut = s.kAttribut
) AS s
PIVOT
(
MAX(cWertVarchar) FOR cName IN (Farbe ,Saison)
) AS pvt
```